# Check missing glyphs in the font file using fontForge

Tags: python, python-2.7, fontforge

I have a Python script that processes fonts using fontForge module.

What is the easiest way to check (using Python fontForge API), that the glyph

with the particular code is missing in the font file?

I checked the Python fontForge API but wasn't able to find the direct
method:

http://dmtr.org/ff.php

https://fontforge.org/docs/scripting/scripting-alpha.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that selects (and checks!) the glyphs:

> SelectIf(arg1, arg2, ...) The same as Select() except that instead of
> signalling an error when a glyph is not in the font it returns an
> error code.
>
> 0 => there were no errors but no glyphs were selected
>
> => there were no errors and this many glyphs were
> selected
>
> -2 => there was an error and no glyphs were selected
>
> -1 => there was an error and at least one glyph was selected before that.

To check if glyph exists or no just type this script:

```
Error(ToString(SelectIf(0u4010, 0u4011, 0u4012)))
```

Probably it will tell "-2" error (no glyphs selected so didn't exist)

If you type

```
Error(ToString(SelectIf(0u410, 0u411, 0u412)))
```

It will tell "3" if a font has cyrillic "АБВ" letters (and select them).
Try it!